# How to make a SWT button call a java class

Tags: java, button, swt, junit4

I have a Driver class (that does not have main method) (actually it has junit annotations @Before, @After etc).
Now i have created a SWT class and created a gui.
Here i want to have a button. Clicking on this button should call the Driver class.

Comment: You'll need to add more information to your question. How do you want to "call" the class?

Comment: I want to call the class on the click of a button (swt button)

Comment: You already said that. Do you want to create a new instance of that class or do you want to call a method in that class? Or do you in general not know how to listen for the click event?

Comment: the class has several methods with jUnit annotations. I dont want to call any particular method but the whole class to get executed on click of button.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should start your jUnit test from a `Button` click:

```
Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("Start test");
button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
{
    public void handleEvent(Event e)
    {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run("your.class.here");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This almost resolved my query. Only a doubt. What s the format of calling the class here.
If i write
Result result = junit.run(myClassName);

it says myClassName cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @user3370488 `myClassName` has to be a string with the path to your class (the package and then the class name like: `"org.test.ui.main"). Please consider accepting my answer if you're happy with the solution.

Comment: if i put it as string 
Result result = junit.run("package.classname");

i get error : junitCore is not applicable to the arguments (String)

Comment: @user3370488 Ah, sorry. Was looking at the wrong method. `junit.run(YouClass.class)` should do it